# Importing and binding multiple and specific csv files into R

Tags: r, csv, import, bind

I would like to import and bind, all together in a R file, specific csv files named as "number.CSV" (e.g. 3437.CSV) which I have got in a folder with other csv files that I do not want to import.

How can I select only the ones that interest me?

I have got a list of all the csv files that I need and in the following column there are some of them.

```
CODE
49002
47001
64002
84008
46003
45001
55008
79005
84014
84009
45003
45005
51001
55012
67005
19004
7003
55023
55003
76004
21013
```

I have got 364 csv files to read and bind.

n.b. I can't select all the "***.csv" files from my folder because I have got other files that I do not need.

Thanks

Comment: do your files have any sort of pattern or naming convention that distinguishes those you need from those you don't?

Comment: hi Benjamin, unfortunately no. they are all named as numbers.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make file names out of your numeric codes:

```
filenames = paste(code, 'csv', sep = '.')
# [1] "49002.csv" "47001.csv" "64002.csv" …
```

You might need to specify the full path to the files as well:

```
directory = '/example/path'
filenames = file.path(directory, filenames)
# [1] "/example/path/49002.csv" "/example/path/47001.csv" "/example/path/64002.csv" …
```

And now you can simply read them into R in one go:

```
data = lapply(filenames, read.csv)
```

Or, if your CSV files don’t have column headers (this is the case, in particular, when the file’s lines have different numbers of items!)

```
data = lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = FALSE)
```

This will give you a `list` of `data.frame`s. If you want to bind them all into one table, use

```
data = do.call(rbind, data)
```

Comment: hi, I tried your code but when I reach lapply I got: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: @Paolo From a comment on another answer I see that your files aren’t actually in a format that R recognises as valid CSV, because the number of columns differ. This is a problem, and you should generally avoid producing such CSV files. Software should never produce such CSVs. That said, you can make R import the files by adding the parameter `header = FALSE`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the list of CSV files of interest, read in each one, and bind it to a common data frame:

```
path <- "path/to/folder/"
ROOT <- c("49002", "47001", "21013")
files <- paste0(path, ROOT)
sapply(files, bindFile, var2=all_files_df)

bindFile <- function(x, all_df) {
    df <- read.csv(x)
    all_df <- rbind(df, all_df)
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I treid to run your code but I got this: > sapply(files, bindFile, var2=all_files_df)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'all_files_df' not found

Comment: @Paolo `all_files_df` needs to be defined by you.  It is the data frame where you want to aggregate everything.  Do all the CSV files have exactly the same structure?

Comment: they have the same columns, but the number of observations change. I rerun the code and I got:  Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
Called from: read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
    dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that from .CSV file. What you can do is open all your data and then use the command `cbind`.

For example:

```
data1 <- read.table("~/YOUR/DATA", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data2 <- read.table("~/YOUR/DATA", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data3 <- read.table("~/YOUR/DATA", quote="\"", comment.char="")
```

And then:

df <- cbind(data1$Col1, data2$col3...)

Where `col` is the name of the column that you want.